# Find images not having an ALT attribute with XPath

Tags: xpath

I want to find images, which doesn't have an ALT attribute (not having it empty, like `alt=""`).

I've tried `//img[not contains(@alt)]`, but it seems to be wrong. Is there a method to match such images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below xpath.

```
//img[not(@alt)]
```